# System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverterAttribute ignored on IOptions<> json classes in .NET6?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have following options class:

```
public class GpsAndTelemetryOptions
{
    public const string Section = "GpsAndTelemetry";

    [JsonConverter(typeof(TimespanConverter))]
    public TimeSpan RealtimeOffset { get; set; } = 200.Milliseconds();
}
```

I am initializing whole environment this way:

```
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(configPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")

                var configuration = builder.Build();
                var services = new ServiceCollection();

.
.
                services.Configure<GpsAndTelemetryOptions>(
                    configuration.GetSection(GpsAndTelemetryOptions.Section));

                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Unfortunately while running following piece of code, the JsonConverterAttribute seems to be ignored. (InvalidOperationException "Failed to convert configuration value ... to type TimeSpan")

```
                var testOptions = (IOptions<GpsAndTelemetryOptions>)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOptions<GpsAndTelemetryOptions>));
                var value = testOptions.Value;
```

Is it somehow possible to instruct the inner deserializer to use JsonConverter attribute? Is it even supported within the System.Text.Json? I am using this approach in a console application. Is there anything else to be configured?

here just an example of the json config file:

```
{
    "GpsAndTelemetry":
    {
        "Uri": "tcp.server://any:5555",
        "RealtimeOffset": "0.700"
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for any hints..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration is not guaranteed to be JSON, actually there a lot of [configuration providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-providers) like environment variables, key vaults, XML files, etc, so configuration is treated as key-value pairs with special binder which is not JSON compatible.

You can try work around that (because configuration binder does not seem to be very extensible) by changing the property type to `int` (and its meaning) and converting in the code when used or via some kind of manual binding (via `IConfigureOptions<TOptions>` for example). Or just provide timespan in `D.HH:mm:nn` format (i.e. days, hours, minutes and seconds).

Comment: This is correct. The simplest solution for the question is to change the confirmation to be `int RealtimeOffsetMs`. All of the configuration providers support int and float properties.

Comment: I tried to avoid having that *Ms suffixes and int type stuff :) I like having such properties with a type where there is not doubt in which units it is.. I know that Ms suffix indicates a lot, but anyway.. :)  Nevermind, thank both of you very much for your advices.
I must confess I didn't know about the D.HH:mm:nn.fff option which is a good one for me.

Comment: What a shame that the configuration binders don't support the TypeConverter, for instance..